# Flutter Reactive-BLE infinite duplicate devices found

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have been using flutter reactive and I have the following problem. When I when I use the function scanForDevices, it displays the found devices duplicate an infinite amount of times. I'm used to using libraries where the found devices appear only one time but this implementation seem to notify you whenever the device makes an advertisement. What can I do to get only one instance of the device? Is my only solution to make a map and add the device id as a key?

Comment: It sounds like a good idea to have a map with already detected devices!

Comment: What kind of device are you detecting multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.every()` method of `List` class

example:

```
_foundBleUARTDevices = [];
_scanning = true;
refreshScreen();
_scanStream =
  flutterReactiveBle.scanForDevices(withServices: []).listen((device) {
    if (_foundBleUARTDevices.every((element) => element.id != device.id)) {
      _foundBleUARTDevices.add(device);
      refreshScreen();
    }
  }, onError: (Object error) {
       _logTexts =
       "${_logTexts}ERROR while scanning:$error \n";
       refreshScreen();
     }
  );
}
```

[for more details](https://github.com/wolfc01/flutter_reactive_ble_uart_example/blob/master/lib/main.dart)

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem where the same devices would be added again and again, even using code like this: `_genericBleDevices_connected.addIf(!_genericBleDevices_connected.contains(device),device);`

The reason for this seems to be, that flutter reactive includes the Rssi value when checking for equality. A solution therfore must use the device Id when checking equality.

Comment: This is actually a clean solution, however, be clear, it is a reactive RxList: https://pub.dev/documentation/observable_ish/latest/list_list/RxList/addIf.html .  Combine with solution below.